# Urban Airship API V3 Push request - 400 Bad request

Tags: urbanairship.com

I am getting 400 - Bad request.

This is my request:

{
    "audience" : {
        "tags": ["994c4298-89ba-4715-879d-10540fcf0059","a82e8789-3239-4899-b6dc-1e6a71dc06d4"]
        },
    "notification": {
            "alert": "19 Aug Test",
            "extra": {"NewsID":"127"}
        },
    "device_types": "all"
}

This is my code:

```
   using (var client = new WebClient())
                string PostData = "I am assigining above json string here";
                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var dataToPost = encoding.GetBytes(PostData);
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";                                        
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept,"application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;");                    
                //client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3";
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("App key", "Master key");
                var result = client.UploadData("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/", "POST", dataToPost);

                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(result);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked when I changed "tags" to "tag" and put "extra" in "ios": {"extra": "blah blah blah"}

I think they have made these changes in V3.

Thanks.